# Class mapping using mapstruct that has an attribute as enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, mapstruct

I have a class called BalanceTarget

```
 public class BalanceTarget   {
  @JsonProperty("amount")
  private String amount;

  public enum CreditDebitIndicatorEnum {
    CREDIT("Credit"),
    
    DEBIT("Debit");

    private String value;

    CreditDebitIndicatorEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static CreditDebitIndicatorEnum fromValue(String value) {
      for (CreditDebitIndicatorEnum b : CreditDebitIndicatorEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
  }

  @JsonProperty("creditDebitIndicator")
  private CreditDebitIndicatorEnum creditDebitIndicator;

  //getter and setters
 
}
```

Another class BalanceSource

```
public class BalanceSource   {
      @JsonProperty("amount")
      private String amount;
    
      public enum CreditDebitIndicatorEnum {
        C("C"),
        
        D("D");
    
        private String value;
    
        CreditDebitIndicatorEnum(String value) {
          this.value = value;
        }
    
        @JsonValue
        public String getValue() {
          return value;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    
        @JsonCreator
        public static CreditDebitIndicatorEnum fromValue(String value) {
          for (CreditDebitIndicatorEnum b : CreditDebitIndicatorEnum.values()) {
            if (b.value.equals(value)) {
              return b;
            }
          }
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
        }
      }
    
      @JsonProperty("creditDebitIndicator")
      private CreditDebitIndicatorEnum creditDebitIndicator;

     //getter and setters
    }
```

I have a mapper for Balance

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = CreditDebitIndicatorMapper.class)
public interface BalanceMapper {

    BalanceTarget convert(BalanceSource a);
}
```

I have another mapper for CreditDebitIndicator

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface CreditDebitIndicatorMapper {
    
        @ValueMapping(source = "C", target = "CREDIT")
        @ValueMapping(source = "D", target = "DEBIT")
        BalanceTarget.CreditDebitIndicatorEnum convert(BalanceSource.CreditDebitIndicatorEnum a);
}
```

On building the code it gives out this error

> The following constants from the property
> "BalanceSource.CreditDebitIndicatorEnum
> balances[].creditDebitIndicator" enum have no corresponding constant
> in the "BalanceTarget.CreditDebitIndicatorEnum
> balances[].creditDebitIndicator" enum and must be be mapped via adding
> additional mappings: C, D.

Comment: What version of mapstruct do you use?

Comment: @Eugene 1.4.2.Final

Comment: I have built your example without issues. Java 1.8, mapstruct 1.4.2.Final, maven-compiler-plugin 3.5.1